# React-select: how to make creatable option optional?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have a react-select component. I know it is possible to use `<CreatableSelect/>` so as to add custom options. But how to make such a behaviour optional? I would like to have something like `<Select creatable={true}/>`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a higher order component which will take the `createable` prop and will return the `Createable` select component if `createable` prop is true otherwise will return the normal `Select` component

```
function SelectHOC({createable, options}) {
    return (
       { createable
            ? <CreatableSelect options={options} />
            : <Select options={options} />
       }
    );
}
```

Comment: Yes I thought about that, but it's not very clean since I pass a lot of options to the select (custom-component, etc.). I would basically have the same 20 lines of code repeated twice. Except if it's possible to store all the props in a const and then easily send it to both Select, I'm reluctant to do it.

Comment: you only need to define those props twice which are different for regular select component and createable select component whereas common props for both types of select component will only need to be defined once.

Comment: Ok, I've used this solution, but no need for a HOC. A simple ternary does the trick.